# Enable/Disable indicator

Tags: guidelines, status

What do you think is the best general way for an icon to be shown disabled , that behaves well in all color circumstances ? e.g desaturating the icon is a good way, but does not behave well in an already gray-scaled icon set .

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just going to list out a few ways of achieving the **disabled** look.

- Although it isn't recommended, you could go with *lowering the opacity*.
- On a pointer-operated screens, use the *disabled pointer* on hover.
- Having gray icons is not really a bottleneck. The idea behind a disabled button is to have a color that is less distinguishable from the background. Try a color that has a slightly higher or lower [tone](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/colour_tone)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a combination of the following:

1) In Web, use hover variation to indicate icon/button's active state.
[Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14750078/style-disabled-button-with-css)

2) Again applicable in Web, you can use the cursor change indicating the disabled state of the icon/button.
[Example](http://codepen.io/DawsonMediaD/pen/Dqrck)

3) In Mobile, desaturating the icon with reducing the opacity could help in highlighting the disabled state. I also experimented by adding a little blur (doable by CSS filters) just to mimic a faded away appearance, so see if that helps. Attaching a quick mockup.

[image]